How do I get a sum of dates logged in? (Assume it's a fixed LOD expression)
Really stuck on this. My data is structured like in columns K:L. I want a calculation that will give me the expected result in column G (6). I'm assuming this is a LOD formula but I've tried a few different ways of approaching that and I keep getting the same incorrect result. Thank you!


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - Please [edit] and provide the code/data/errors as text.

Im assuming you want to count the number of monthly periods where a user had activity on at least one day. That is multiple events within the same month would count only once and that events in different years would count separately.  Given those assumptions, define a calculated field called say month_year as
Date_trunc(“month”, [date])

Put user_id on the row shelf and month_year on the text shelf. Click on month_year on the text shelf and choose to treat it as a measure with the Count Distinct aggregation function
